# Javascript Namespace: local variable has been updated but not the public one

Tags: javascript, oop, namespaces

I have a namespace MyNameSpace which has a public variable **Name** and public methods **SayName** and **ChangeName**

```
 var MyNameSpace = MyNameSpace|| function () {

       var _name = "John";

        function _SayMyName() {
         return _name;
        }

        function _changeMyName(newName) {
          _name = newName;
        }

        return {
           SayName: _SayMyName,
           ChangeName : _changeMyName,
           Name:_name 
        }
    }();

alert(MyNameSpace.SayName()) // John
MyNameSpace.ChangeName("Paul")
alert(MyNameSpace.SayName()) // Paul
alert(MyNameSpace.Name)      // John
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptr15ty0/)

**MyNameSpace.Name** will always return John even if **_Name** has been changed. Why?
**MyNameSpace.Name** doesn't hold a reference to **_Name**?

What to do so **MyNameSpace.Name**  returns the same value as **_Name**?

Comment: You're returning a copy of `_name` in your object, not a reference to the property.

Comment: As you say yourself, they're two distinct variables (or actually, one is a property not a variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a Object which `Name` property holds a copy of `_name`. The value of `_name`is copied by value, not by reference, that's why it does not change.

You could write this, to mimic your desired behaviour:

```
return {
    get Name () { return _name; },
    //if you like to have a setter, than:
    set Name (n) { _name = n; }
    //the other properties go here...
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you

Comment: Nice to hear that I could help!